# Find only date attributes in ActiveRecord object with mixed column types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord object that has attributes that are either integers or dates. I need to find and return the oldest date (ignoring the created_at and updated_at fields).

I thought I would be able to do a query for only the attributes with a type of date and then sort from there, but either that's not possible or I can't get the syntax right.

I can get the values into an array with `Object.find(x).attributes.values.compact` but this includes the created_at and updated_at values as well as integers and then I'm still stuck on how to sort the result by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude not dates and both `timestamp`s, you should do it explicitly:

```
Object.find(x).
  attributes.
  reject { |k, _| %w[created_at updated_at].include? k }.
  select { |_, v| v.is_a? Date }.
  values.
  sort.
  last
```

Comment: `reject { |k, _| %w[created_at updated_at].include? k }`. Why not `except('created_at', 'updated_at')`?

Comment: @Leo also works with except and saves a little space, thank you too!

Comment: @Leo basically because `except` is `Rails` and I try to avoid rails monkeypatching  bullshit whenever possible.